# jQuery : fire callback only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

How to tell jQuery to fire a callback function only once ?

```
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function callback_function() {
    console.log('callback function') // fired twice, on 'ready' and 'turbolinks:load' events
});
```

I want the callback_function to be called on "ready", on "turbolinks:load", but not twice if both events occurs on the same page.

Edit : I'm aware of the jQuery one() function, that doesn't answer the question actually. According to the jQuery docs, "The handler is executed at most once per element per event type." I want the reverse : the handler to be executed once for all event types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unbind a callback by using [jQuery.off](https://api.jquery.com/off/) and using a counter for the maximum amount of repetitions. With [`.one`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) the callback is executed once for each event, which is undesirable

```js
let count = 0;
function callbackWithCounter(event) {
  if (count++ >= 1){
    $(this).off(event)
    return;
  }
  console.log("button clicked " + count);
}

function simpleCallback(event) {
  console.log("button clicked");
}

$('#clickme').one("click mousedown mouseup", simpleCallback);
$('#clickme-two').on("click mousedown mouseup", callbackWithCounter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='clickme'>Click me using .one</button><br/>
<button id='clickme-two'>Click me with a counter and .off</button>
```

You can also make a helper function for managing these limited-life callbacks

```js
//a wrapper that will ensure the callback "self-destructs" and will be unbound correctly
function makeSelfDestructingEventCallback(maxExecutions, callback) {
  let count = 0;
  
  return function(event) {
    if (count++ >= maxExecutions){
      $(this).off(event)
      return;
    }
    //pass any normal arguments down to the wrapped callback
    return callback.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

function callback(event) {
  console.log("button clicked");
}

$('#clickme').on("click mousedown mouseup", makeSelfDestructingEventCallback(1, callback));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='clickme'>Click me</button>
```

And here is the same thing in a curried form

```js
//a curried wrapper that will ensure the callback "self-destructs" and will be unbound correctly
function makeSelfDestructingEventCallback(maxExecutions) {
  return function(callback) {
    let count = 0;
    return function(event) {
      if (count++ >= maxExecutions){
        $(this).off(event)
        return;
      }
      //pass any normal arguments down to the wrapped callback
      return callback.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
  
}

function callback(event) {
  console.log("button clicked");
}

let one = makeSelfDestructingEventCallback(1);
let two = makeSelfDestructingEventCallback(2);

$('#clickme').on("click mousedown mouseup", one(callback));
$('#clickme-two').on("click mousedown mouseup", two(callback));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='clickme'>Click me - single execution</button><br/>
<button id='clickme-two'>Click me - executes twice</button>
```